# Can't insert object in the array, that I want add to User Defaults

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have initialization of the array

```
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var initObject: [CPaymentInfo]? = defaults.objectForKey("paymentData") as? [CPaymentInfo]
    if initObject == nil {
        initObject = [CPaymentInfo]()
        defaults.setValue(initObject, forKey: "paymentData")
    }
    defaults.synchronize()
```

And I have the Controller, that contains two text labels and two buttons: Save and Cancel (Both calling the segue)

```
    if sender as? UIBarButtonItem == saveButton {
        var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var payments: [CPaymentInfo]? = defaults.objectForKey("paymentData") as? [CPaymentInfo]
        var newPaymentItem: CPaymentInfo?
        if discriptionField.hasText() {
            newPaymentItem = CPaymentInfo(value: (valueField.text as NSString).doubleValue, discription: discriptionField.text)
        } else {
            newPaymentItem = CPaymentInfo(value: (valueField.text as NSString).doubleValue)
        }

        if let newPay = newPaymentItem {
            payments?.insert(newPay, atIndex: 0)
        }
        defaults.setObject(payments, forKey: "paymentData")
    }
```

But it doesn't work and app crashes.
I found that I can just set "payments" as new object in defaults for key without changing
(By commenting of block with insert).
Also I found, that I can comment line with setObject method only and apps will work too. How I can do what I want?

---

> 2015-07-14 20:34:34.403 cash app[15156:1494701] Property list invalid
>   for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type
>   'CFType') 2015-07-14 20:34:34.404 cash app[15156:1494701] Attempt to
>   set a non-property-list object (
>       "cash_app.CPaymentInfo" ) as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key paymentData 2015-07-14 20:34:34.409 cash app[15156:1494701]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property
>   list object (
>       "cash_app.CPaymentInfo" ) for key paymentData'

Comment: "app crashes", please provide more details, stack trace and detailed error message.

Comment: Read `NSUserDefaults` documentation. Quote: _A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData._ If you read error message, it states same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the error message:

```
Attempt to insert non-property list object ( "cash_app.CPaymentInfo" ) for key paymentData'
```

You cannot put arbitrary classes into a property list (such as `NSUserDefaults`). There is a specific list of classes that are acceptable. If you have other classes you want to store, you need to convert them to an acceptable class.

For documentation on saving non-property-list classes to user defaults, see [Storing NSColor in UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/StoringNSColorInDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001693). While that article focuses on `NSColor`, it applies to any object that conforms to `NSCoding`. See also the Note at [Introduction to Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html).