# Can `AnyObject` in Swift handle any type of objects? Really?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3, anyobject

**I'm asking this question to know what `AnyObject` means. I've resolved my error though.**

I've a class using to store some user values, lets say

```
class UserDetails : NSObject
{
    var name : String?

    init(name : String)
    {
        super.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

and I'm storing a object of class `UserDetails` to `NSUserDefaults` as

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userData, forKey: "user_details")
```

the above line not displaying any error to me as methods `setObject` takes argument of type `AnyObject?` but at the time of execution its displaying the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object <Sample.UserDetails: 0x7b1189b0> for key user_details'
```

- So, Why I'm not able to store the object of type `UserDetails`.
- What is the actual type of `AnyObject`
- Why it is thrown `InvalidArgumentException`.

I really need to the difference and What type of objects `AnyObject` can handle?

Thank you.

Comment: @vacawama I asked this question to know `AnyObject` actual mean. I've resolved my error. You can help me to edit this question if i'm not to the point.

Comment: *AnyObject* is a protocol to which all classes conform.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31766860/1630618

Comment: Protocols are the rules, AnyObject defines those rules, All classes must conform those. Which means my Class do that too. So Why we can not store its object to NSUserDefault?

Comment: Because you can't just store any old object in `NSUserDefaults`.  It needs to be a "property-list".  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31410220/1630618

Comment: Unfortunately, a "property-list" isn't a type so `NSUserDefaults` takes `AnyObject`, but there are additional run-time restrictions on how that object is constructed.

Comment: Exactly. So the problem is about what NSUserDefaults can store, and unrelated to what AnyObject can handle. If you search for the message "Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults" then you'll find some similar Q&As, both Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: @MartinR, I closed this as a duplicate of that question, and then the OP insisted that they were instead asking about what *AnyObject* was, which is why we ended up here.  I agree that this should be closed as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: I had not noticed that the question had been closed and reopened before. – However, both *"Why I'm not able to store the object of type UserDetails"* and *"Why it is thrown InvalidArgumentException"* are answered in the referenced Q&A. What remains is *"What is the actual type of AnyObject"*, and that is answered in the documentation as (as you said), "a protocol to which all classes conform".

Comment: I was asking why we can not store object of type of some classes even if the NSUserDefault take argument of type `AnyObject`. This actually contradictory to `AnyObject` mean. It should handle all type of objects. May be apple do not allow this to store in UserDefaults but why? However I do not get my answer. You can close this if you want and treat it as duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: @AmitSingh, the types a function takes does not necessarily indicate the full range of *legal* inputs.  For instance, `sqrt` takes a `Double`, but that doesn't mean `-3.0` is a legal input.  Likewise, `setObject` takes `AnyObject` but the list of legal inputs is more limited than that.

Comment: AnyObject can handle _any_ object. NSUserDefaults can't.